# How to merge rows that have multiple levels for specific columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

### My data

I am working with the following data from the [National Centers for Environmental Information (NCEI)](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/) - obtained simply by using pandas' `read_html()`.

```
df = pd.read_html('https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/monitoring/climate-at-a-glance/statewide/rankings/1/tavg/202302')[0]

df.head()


                   Period            Value  1901-2000Mean   Anomaly Rank(1895-2023) Warmest/CoolestSince    Record
0   February 2023 1-Month   56.6°F(13.7°C)  48.0°F(8.9°C)   8.6°F(4.8°C)    126th Coolest   Coolest since:2022  1895
1   February 2023 1-Month   56.6°F(13.7°C)  48.0°F(8.9°C)   8.6°F(4.8°C)    4th Warmest Warmest since:2018  2018
2   Jan–Feb 2023 2-Month    54.0°F(12.2°C)  46.5°F(8.1°C)   7.5°F(4.1°C)    127th Coolest   Coolest since:2022  1978
3   Jan–Feb 2023 2-Month    54.0°F(12.2°C)  46.5°F(8.1°C)   7.5°F(4.1°C)    3rd Warmest Warmest since:2017  1950
```

### My problem/desired output

The `Rank (YYYY-YYYY)` and `Warmest/CoolestSince` columns have two "levels" to them, meaning each row is replicated to account for each level. My desired output would be the following

```
                   Period            Value  1901-2000Mean   Anomaly      CoolestRank(1895-2023) CoolestSince    CoolestRecord WarmestRank(1895-2023)WarmestSince WarmestRecord
0   February 2023 1-Month   56.6°F(13.7°C)  48.0°F(8.9°C)   8.6°F(4.8°C)        126th Coolest   Coolest since:2022  1895    4th Warmest       Warmest since:2018    2018
1   Jan–Feb 2023 2-Month    54.0°F(12.2°C)  46.5°F(8.1°C)   7.5°F(4.1°C)        127th Coolest   Coolest since:2022  1978    3rd Warmest       Warmest since:2017    1950
```

So basically, I'd like to combine all unique `Period` rows and add new columns to take care of the two columns with multiple levels.

### What I have tried

My initial thought was something not very practical - what if I took the two `Rank (YYYY-YYYY)` and `Warmest/CoolestSince` values from each odd row (the second of each duplicated `Period` and use those to populate two new columns, then drop each odd row? Something like this could be done, but probably isn't very efficient, pythonic, etc.

Then I thought, since we have groups of unique `Period` values, that maybe I could do some sort of `groupby` magic? Since the warmth related columns are always the lower level, I can do something like:

```
(df
 .groupby('Period')
 .agg(
     Value=('Value','first'),
     Anomaly=('Anomaly','first'),
     CoolestSince=('Warmest/CoolestSince','first'),
     CoolestRecord=('Record','first'),
     WarmestSince=('Warmest/CoolestSince','last'),
     WarmestRecord=('Record','last'),
     )
 )
```

to achieve my desired output. However, this type of aggregation doesn't work for assigning columns with non-alphabetic characters. I get an error when I try to add the other columns:

```
(df
 .groupby('Period')
 .agg(
     Value=('Value','first'),
     1901-2000Mean=('1901-2000Mean','first'),
     Anomaly=('Anomaly','first'),
     CoolestRank(1895-2023)=('Rank(1895-2023)','first'),
     CoolestSince=('Warmest/CoolestSince','first'),
     CoolestRecord=('Record','first'),
     WarmestRank(1895-2023)=('Rank(1895-2023)','last'),
     WarmestSince=('Warmest/CoolestSince','last'),
     WarmestRecord=('Record','last'),
     )
 )


SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Is there a way to assign `groupby` columns via strings? I tried formatting it into a dictionary but I couldn't seem to get it to work. Is there an alternative solution that is more efficient? I am curious, as what I am on to seems to be a pretty solid solution.

NOTE: Although not listed in the data preview of this question, occasionally there is a third level to a column for ties between years. These can be ignored, as I am just dropping these rows with `df.loc[~df.Value.str.contains('Ties')]`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, assigning string in [`df.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) and then [`df.droplevel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html), and finally [`df.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```py
df = (df.groupby('Period')
        .agg({
            'Value': 'first',
            '1901-2000Mean': 'first',
            'Anomaly': 'first',
            'Rank(1895-2023)': [('CoolestRank(1895-2023)', 'first'), ('WarmestRank(1895-2023)', 'last')],
            'Warmest/CoolestSince': [('CoolestSince', 'first'), ('WarmestSince', 'last')],
            'Record': [('CoolestRecord', "first"), ('WarmestRecord', 'last')]
        }).droplevel(1, axis=1)
          .reset_index()
       )

# Rename columns
df.columns = ['Period', 'Value', '1901-2000Mean', 'Anomaly', 
              'CoolestRank(1895-2023)', 'WarmestRank(1895-2023)', 'CoolestSince', 
              'WarmestSince', 'CoolestRecord', 'WarmestRecord']

print(df)
```

---

```
                  Period           Value  1901-2000Mean       Anomaly CoolestRank(1895-2023) WarmestRank(1895-2023)        CoolestSince        WarmestSince  CoolestRecord  WarmestRecord
0  February 2023 1-Month  56.6°F(13.7°C)  48.0°F(8.9°C)  8.6°F(4.8°C)          126th Coolest            4th Warmest  Coolest since:2022  Warmest since:2018           1895           2018
1   Jan–Feb 2023 2-Month  54.0°F(12.2°C)  46.5°F(8.1°C)  7.5°F(4.1°C)          127th Coolest            3rd Warmest  Coolest since:2022  Warmest since:2017           1978           1950
```

If you want to re-order columns, add this snippet to the code:

```
df = df[['Period', 'Value', '1901-2000Mean', 'Anomaly', 
         'CoolestRank(1895-2023)', 'CoolestSince', 'CoolestRecord', 
         'WarmestRank(1895-2023)', 'WarmestSince', 'WarmestRecord']]
```

---

```
                  Period           Value  1901-2000Mean       Anomaly CoolestRank(1895-2023)        CoolestSince  CoolestRecord WarmestRank(1895-2023)        WarmestSince  WarmestRecord
0  February 2023 1-Month  56.6°F(13.7°C)  48.0°F(8.9°C)  8.6°F(4.8°C)          126th Coolest  Coolest since:2022           1895            4th Warmest  Warmest since:2018           2018
1   Jan–Feb 2023 2-Month  54.0°F(12.2°C)  46.5°F(8.1°C)  7.5°F(4.1°C)          127th Coolest  Coolest since:2022           1978            3rd Warmest  Warmest since:2017           1950
```